Eliminar datos de BD con admin-ajax.php
tengo problemas para invocar admin-ajax.php para eliminar registros en la bd.
Estoy dentro de un plugin en desarrollo llamado dm-calculator.
Esto va en la pagina dm-calculator.php (inicial)
function EncolarDMCalculatorJS($hook)
{
    //echo "<script>console.log('$hook')</script>";
    if ($hook != 'dm-calculator/admin/listar_data.php')
    {
        return;
    }
    

    $ajax_url = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );

    wp_enqueue_script('EncolarDMCalculatorJS',plugins_url('admin/js/lista_data.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('EncolarDMCalculatorJS','SolicitudesAjax',[
        'url'=> $ajax_url,
        'seguridad'=>wp_create_nonce('seg')
    ]);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','EncolarDMCalculatorJS');

function EliminarRegistro(){
    $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
    if(!wp_verify_nonce($nonce,'seg')){
        die('No tiene permisos para ejecutar');
    }

    $id= $_POST['id'];
    global $wpdb;
    $tabla    = "{$wpdb->prefix}TipoDeCambio";
    $wpdb->delete($tabla,array('codtc'=>$id));
    wp_die();
    //return true;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_peticioneliminar','EliminarRegistro');

Y esto va en el archivo js
 $(document).on('click',"a[data-id]",function(){
                try{
                var id = this.dataset.id;
               // console.log(id);
                var url = SolicitudesAjax.url;
                console.log(url);
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:url,
                    data: {
                        action: "peticionEliminar",
                        nonce: SolicitudesAjax.seguridad,
                        id: id 
                    },
                    success: function(){
                        location.reload();
                    }
                });
            }catch (error) {
                console.error(errorThrown);
                
              }

        });

En este proceso, llega al javascript(ya lo probé con alerts y genera la url hacia admin-ajax.php) pero me sale este error 400

Agradezco de antemano sus comentarios. Saludos!

Por favor no hagas tantas publicaciones relacionadas con la misma pregunta, si las respuestas anteriores no te sirvieron entonces haz debug, si no puedes solucionarlo actualiza tu pregunta original mostrando los resultados del debug, tal y como esta no podemos saber porque falla, si no debugeas seguirás en las mismas sin importar cuantas preguntas de lo mismo hagas.
